# Using awk to separate an output containing a tab and a "/" separators into a delimited format

Tags: linux, unix, awk

I'll appreciate help in converting this output to a pipe delimited

I have the following output

```
abcde1234 /path/A/file1
test23455 /path/B/file2345
```

But I would like in

```
abcde1234|file1
test23455|file2345
```

Comment: Do you need to use `awk`? Seems like `sed` would be simpler.

Comment: Assuming no space in the first token (here's sed) - `sed -e 's#  *\([^/]*/\)*\([^/]*\)$#|\2#'`

Comment: I'll prefer to use awk but I'm open to any solution that is readable (clean)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

try to use `cut` ‍♀️.

```
abcde1234 /path/A/file1
test23455 /path/B/file2345
```

```
while IFS= read -r line; do
  value1=$(echo $line | cut -d ' ' -f1)
  value2=$(echo $line | cut -d '/' -f4)
  printf "$value1 $value2\n"
done < <(cat list)
```

Answer (score 1):

In `awk`, If you set `FS` as `[[:blank:]]+/|/` you can print the first and last fields:

```
awk -v FS='[[:blank:]]+/|/' -v OFS='|' '{print $1, $NF}' file
abcde1234|file1
test23455|file2345
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a one-liner `awk` solution:

```
awk -v FS='[ \t].*/' -v OFS='|' '{$1=$1}1' file
```

and, a `sed` one-liner:

```
sed 's%[[:blank:]].*/%|%' file
```

and a pure `bash` one

```
while read -r; do echo "${REPLY%%[[:blank:]]*}|${REPLY##*/}"; done < file
```